# How disable check constraint on connection

Tags: jackcess, ucanaccess

java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:///user/dev/project/project.mdb")

I have this error

Java::NetUcanaccessJdbc::UcanaccessSQLException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10991 table: EMPLOYE column: DATE

I doesn't want control integrity at the connection, what is the property parameter to disable check contrainte at the connection ?

Thank for your help

Comment: i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525713/how-to-enable-referential-integrity-in-hsql-db-in-memory-unit-tests, but how execute statement in java program ?

Comment: You can't, you should get the connection before creating statement. And the constraint physically written on your accdb/mdb and it's enabled. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this exception is thrown at the connection time, it means that the database data are inconsistent with its contraints: ucanaccess is properly building a dbms layer with all integrity contraints but the  creation of one of those constraints fails.

You can't disable it, ucanaccess must create all constraints so that  when you try to insert/update/delete a record, all related  constraints are checked and your db consistent state is preserved.

Why don't you drop the not null constraint  in the database table definition?(you have just to set the "required" property, on the mentioned column, from true to false). It doesn't seem to be taken into account...

Comment: the database is used by application client/server, i can't modify it. I want to have access to read-only to execute select statements. This exception is not generated by hsqldb ?

Comment: Yes, because hsqldb is the "mirror" dbms. Ucanaccess does the "conversion" from the constraints that it has just read with jackcess and the constraints on hsqldb. So it creates them on hsqldb, but they  physically are on your mdb. Yes, I understand your issue, but maybe the only thing I can do is to implement a readonly connection parameter (it's already in my plan).  In this case only, I'll avoid to create any constraint on hsqldb.

Comment: Also, it could be useful to report to the mdb administrator that the mdb is currently in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Thank jamadei for your comments and your job, the readonly connection parameter it's good idea. I have deleted row with integrity constraint violation and now, i have two others problems. 1/ There are link tables with another mdb file with windows path. I am on linux, this doesn't work. Message : WARNING:given file does not exist: x:\project\project_other.mdb and Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.  Can i skip the link tables at the connection ? 2/ After link tables problems, my database is now read-only...

Comment: It's just a warning(the external links will be skipped), but you can use the Remap connection parameter to link the external databases on linux. About the memory issue, you can either increase the VM Xmx or use the memory=false setting. See the ucanaccess web site for more details.

Comment: with memory=false, that ok. My database is very tall, and the database tests are very long. If i understand, the tests are executed to control the database consistent before execute an insert, delete, update.

Comment: The mirror db is created at the very first connection, in the whole VM life,  to one specific mdb/accdb(yes, of course, before any insert, delete, update). The following connections in the vm life will take an insignificant time. You can see the very first connection time as a start-up time.

Comment: yes, the first connection : 12 minutes, after, this is instantaneous.

Comment: If you are sure the database doesn't change(it's read only), you can also use the KeepMirror parameter. Connections will be instantaneous, from the second connection until the next change to the database done by an external process, regardless a vm process restart.

Comment: My application doesn't change data, but client/server yes. My application and client/server application access to database in same time.

Comment: In this specific case (big database and/or not enough memory to use the "in memory mode" by increasing the  Xmx, and concurrent processes accessing and/or updating  to the database) the UCanAccess  isn't a  suitable solution(or it isn't still suitable).
At each access from your application after a concurrent update from the client/server application UCanAccess will try to upgrade the mirror database, with resulting unacceptable performances.

Comment: I don't understand keepMirror paramater. How the mirror hsqldb database is kept after the VM ends. I am on Os x. After stop and start process, the first connection is always 12 minutes. If an external process change the data and the keepMirror parameter is used, the next connection is slow ?

Comment: ok, i understand, yes, UCanAccess is not solution, thank you very much jamadei for your help.